# Polymorphic relationship with nullable id

Tags: mysql, laravel, database-design

Is it a bad practice to use null id entries in a table with polymorphic relationship to store default values?

For example, there is a table of meta tags:

| id | entity_type | entity_id | title | description | keywords |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | App\Models\Product | null | Buy {name} at Best Price in {sitename} | {description:100}... | buy {name}, best price, with warranty, |
| 2 | App\Models\Product | 10 | Buy Rubik's Cube for speedcubing (3x3x3 puzzle) in ExampleShop | The Rubik's Cube is not just a toy, it's an example for my stackoverflow question. | Buy Rubik's Cube, speedcubing, 3x3x3 puzzle |

An entry with `null` value in the `entity_id` column contains the default meta tags for all `App\Model\Product`. The second entry contains the meta tags for the `Product` with `id = 10`, which will be used instead of the default values.

What do you think about it? Is this a bad solution or not?

UPD. The raw query for example:

```sql
select `products`.`id`, `products`.`name`, 
  coalesce(`mt`.`title`, `mt_default`.`title`) `mt_title`,
  coalesce(`mt`.`description`, `mt_default`.`description`) `mt_description`,
  coalesce(`mt`.`keywords`, `mt_default`.`keywords`) `mt_keywords`
from `products`
left join `meta_tags` `mt` on (`mt`.`entity_id` = `products`.`id` and `mt`.`entity_type` = 'App\Models\Product')
left join `meta_tags` `mt_default` on (`mt_default`.`entity_id` IS NULL and `mt_default`.entity_type = 'App\Models\Product')
```

Comment: Under what circumstances do you use #1 versus #2?

Comment: I'm thinking of using #1 for products without meta tags. E.g. there is no  entry in the meta_tags table for the product with id 12, so we can use the default value from #1.

Comment: Let's see the queries to use this table.

Comment: I'm thinking of using this solution with Laravel, but I've added a raw sql-query example to the question.

Comment: Caution!  Backslashes may cause trouble in strings like `'App\Models\Product'`.

Comment: This is ugly, IMO. The default values should be part of your codebase. If they must be dynamic, they should be stored elsewhere with other sitewide settings. The answer below is coming at this strictly from a DB perspective, without considering the Laravel context.

Comment: @miken32 That's the answer I wanted. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

`mt` and `mt_default` both need `INDEX(entity_id, entity_type)` (Either order is OK.)

Backslashes (`\`) hare special characters in MySQL strings.  I strongly recommend avoiding them strings that don't need their special usage.

As for `NULLs` -- There are many valid reasons for having `NULL` values.  The query you presented is a bit clumsy to write, but it works and does what you need.  There is not necessarily a better way to write the query.

Comment: OK, thank you. But the question is not about indexes and data types. It's about architecture. The main question is: "Is it a bad practice to use null id entries in a table with polymorphic relationship to store default values?"

Comment: @Pyramidhead - Oops.  I added a paragraph on that.